# IF-ELSE condition creating loop for new activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im new to Android Studio. So, im trying to use IF-Else statement to retrive data from firebase using radio button. When click on submit button, it should open a new activity and all of the data should display in one page using listview. But, instead of one page, the output display in many activites. Each activity contain one data. I think its because of my if else statement. Can someone help me? Thank you

So this is my code for SelectAge.class

```
    public class SelectAge extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button sbmit;
        RadioGroup rg1,rg2;
        RadioButton rb1,rb2;
        DatabaseReference dr;
        EditText et;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_age);

        rg1 = findViewById(R.id.A1);
        rg2 = findViewById(R.id.A2);
        dr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Data");
        sbmit = findViewById(R.id.SubmitBtn);
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> ad;




        sbmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int radioID1 = rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int radioID2 = rg2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                rb1 = findViewById(radioID1);
                rb2 = findViewById(radioID2);



                dr.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {



                            if (rb1.getText().equals(snapshot.child("Age").getValue()) && (!rb2.getText().equals(snapshot.child("Allergy").getValue()
                            ))) {


                                String ingredient = snapshot.child("Ingredient").getValue().toString();


                                Intent intent = new Intent(SelectAge.this, result.class);

                                intent.putExtra("Result", ingredient);
                                startActivity(intent);


                            }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    public void checkButton(View v){
        int radioID1 = rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        int radioID2 = rg2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        rb1 = findViewById(radioID1);
        rb2 = findViewById(radioID2);

        Toast.makeText(SelectAge.this,"Select" +rb1.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

My sample data
[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: The activities opened according to the number of data. I was expecting to display all the data in one page/activity. More specific, in listview.

Answer (score 0):

In your use case do not use `dr.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {...});`

While using a ChildEventListener is the recommended way to read lists of data, there are situations where attaching a ValueEventListener to a list reference is useful.

Attaching a ValueEventListener to a list of data will return the entire list of data as a single DataSnapshot, which you can then loop over to access individual children.

Even when there is only a single match for the query, the snapshot is still a list; it just contains a single item. To access the item, you need to loop over the result:

```
dr.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        if (rb1.getText().equals(snapshot.child("Age").getValue()) && (!rb2.getText().equals(snapshot.child("Allergy").getValue()
                    ))) {


                        String ingredient = snapshot.child("Ingredient").getValue().toString();


                        Intent intent = new Intent(SelectAge.this, result.class);

                        intent.putExtra("Result", ingredient);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return; // stop looping we have found our item


                    }
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // Getting Post failed, log a message
    Log.w(TAG, "loadIngredient:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    // ...
}});
```

Detailed information in [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much now its only have one page. But, how can i retrieve all the data in that page? Because when i try it, it only display the first data. Do i need to use arraylist?

Comment: Provide a sample of your data.

Comment: I've put a screenshot of my data in firebase

Comment: Query the data you need on the page.

Comment: I will try that. Hopefully i can do it. Thank you so much